# Elegant way to use a non-entity class for ProcedureCall.createStoredProcedureCall()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

From the title itself, is there a better way to map the result directly to a non-entity class. I tried to use `resultSetMappings` to directly map the result to the class but in my scenario I got more than 20 columns of data so its a long set of column mapping, its just like looping it and manually mapping the data. I also want to know it to lessen my future coding when using native query with sets of custom column
Is there a other way like

```
@NonEntityMapper
public class Object1{
    //  20+ attributes
}
```

So I could use it in

```
createStoredProcedureCall("SP_NAME", Object1.class)
```

Comment: We can map to Interface definition

Comment: I'm also thinking creating custom @Annotation to handle non-entity mapping, but no luck